# Notepad++ How do you copy and insert a new line with some edited content

Tags: notepad++

I have lines of code as follows:

```
Some text SELLO S-2 BREAK &Logic,0
Some other text SELLO S-2_BREAKTWO &Logic,0
Wear EXT &SELO-344 S-2,0,30
```

Is it possible to copy and insert a new edited line after finding S-2 and replace S-2 for S-4 as follows?

```
Some text SELLO S-2 BREAK &Logic,0
Some text SELLO S-4 BREAK &Logic,0
Some other text SELLO S-2_BREAKTWO &Logic,0
Some other text SELLO S-4_BREAKTWO &Logic,0
Wear EXT &SELO-344 S-2,0,30
Wear EXT &SELO-344 S-4,0,30
```

Comment: How is this replacing?

Comment: You actually could use the find and replace dialog in Regular Expression mode within Notepad++ for this. You would build a group for lines consisting of a start, the string you want to change and the end and replace it with something like `$0\r\n$1S-2$2`.

Answer (score 0):

1. open find and replace dialog in notepad++

   - check "regular expression"
   - make sure that ". matches newline" is not checked
2. find what: `^(.*)S-2(.*)$`
   replace with: `$0\n$1S-4$2`
3. press "replace all"

See how it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/UW9BL3/1).